# Get j_username before having authentication completed

Tags: java, jsf, spring-security

I constructed a filter that runs before the ***"springSecurityFilterChain"*** and this filter needs the j_username for its ***doFilter*** method. 
Unfortuntaly it's impossible to use a Principal object and get the username throught ***getName()*** before the end of a successful authentication.
Is there any other way to get the ***j_username*** in this first filter?

Comment: What exactly do you need it for? (and for which you thus possibly incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution)

Comment: In fact, this first filter is used to identify the tenant which the user belongs and therefore rout the application to the appropriate database.  
Hence I need a first filter to identify the tenant and the needed database to work with.

Comment: Take a look at JASPIC. Nothing can be done from JSF or Servlet (Filter) side (as that otherwise invites potential security holes).

Comment: You can't 'identify the tenant to which the user belongs' until you identify the user, and you can't identity the user until he has authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override

```
 public class ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

 @Override
 public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
          final String username = request.getParameter("j_username");

          // delegate your logic
          return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); 
  } 
}
```

in security config < http />

```
<bean id="exUsernamePasswordAuthFilter" class="..." />

<custom-filter ref="exUsernamePasswordAuthFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters

Comment: this helps alot, I greatly appreciate your help Kxyz !